# Déjà vu, again?

Tags: word, wordplay

There is a very special property common to all the words below:

```
ART

BAIL

LAP

LATTE

MEAT

ON

PEAR

PEAS

RED

RUM

SCENE

SHOT

SIGN

TINES
```

Stuck?  Need a hint?  Here's that list again:

```
ART

BAIL

LAP

LATTE

MEAT

ON

PEAR

PEAS

RED

RUM

SCENE

SHOT

SIGN

TINES
```

---

**Epilogue:**

Fast solve, @Deusovi !

One minor variant:

> Another anagram for LAP+LAP is APPALL

Comment: Heh, this couldve been a very decent What Is A Word? style puzzle

Comment: Maybe if both columns had the same words. It is deja vu after all.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The property these words have is that

> you can double them and anagram to form a new word: TARTAR, BILABIAL, PALPAL, TATTLETALE, TEAMMATE, NOON, REAPPEAR, APPEASES, REDDER, MURMUR, SENESCENCE, HOTSHOTS, SIGNINGS, INTESTINES.

Comment: I started Ghost Trick after looking at your profile, and now it's like I am playing a game controlling a real person. Sheesh...

Comment: Can you share the journey on how you found the property? It seems hard.

Comment: @justhalf The puzzle itself is a pretty big clue. Also, many of these are reasonably well known; it wouldn't surprise me in the least if Deusovi recognized the answer just from the last two on the list. Add SCENE and it's nearly a sure thing.

Comment: Yeah, the puzzle presentation itself was the main hint. Once I saw the last word, I immediately saw the anagram (since it's really not much of a change from just doubling it), and at that point the other words were just verification.