# Flip over all the cards

Tags: wordplay

Just as you flip over a deck of cards, we will be flipping over a deck of lettered "cards" from left to right, forming words all along the way.

Watch this example:

```
Here are the "cards" spread across the table: 

  EWTTOR      ILER      VER     RTS     SSED      RTS     ETS     LED     TED     CTIVE


Start by flipping over the first card.  It will join to the second card, forming a word:

        ROTTWEILER      VER     RTS     SSED      RTS     ETS     LED     TED     CTIVE


Take a few moments to admire the word you've created.
When you're ready, divide the word into two new cards...

        ROTTW EILER     VER     RTS     SSED      RTS     ETS     LED     TED     CTIVE


... in such a way that when you flip over the second card, it forms a new word with the next card: 

        ROTTW      RELIEVER     RTS     SSED      RTS     ETS     LED     TED     CTIVE


Then divide that word into two cards (being mindful that it might not divide at the same place where you previously stuck it together!)

        ROTTW      RELI EVER    RTS     SSED      RTS     ETS     LED     TED     CTIVE


Now flip over the second card to form a new word with the next card:

        ROTTW      RELI     REVERTS     SSED      RTS     ETS     LED     TED     CTIVE


And so forth, all the way to the end:

        ROTTW      RELI     REV ERTS    SSED      RTS     ETS     LED     TED     CTIVE

        ROTTW      RELI     REV     STRESSED      RTS     ETS     LED     TED     CTIVE

        ROTTW      RELI     REV     STR ESSED     RTS     ETS     LED     TED     CTIVE

        ROTTW      RELI     REV     STR      DESSERTS     ETS     LED     TED     CTIVE

        ROTTW      RELI     REV     STR      DESS ERTS    ETS     LED     TED     CTIVE

        ROTTW      RELI     REV     STR      DESS     STREETS     LED     TED     CTIVE

        ROTTW      RELI     REV     STR      DESS     STR EETS    LED     TED     CTIVE

        ROTTW      RELI     REV     STR      DESS     STR     STEELED     TED     CTIVE

        ROTTW      RELI     REV     STR      DESS     STR     STE ELED    TED     CTIVE

        ROTTW      RELI     REV     STR      DESS     STR     STE     DELETED     CTIVE

        ROTTW      RELI     REV     STR      DESS     STR     STE     DEL ETED    CTIVE

        ROTTW      RELI     REV     STR      DESS     STR     STE     DEL     DETECTIVE


We did it!
```

Now see if you can do this one on your own:

```
IORB    LER     VED     ATED      LED     VER     VED     SED     RED     VED     LED     MIT     NG
```

*This is just a funny little puzzle for those who are looking for a delightful and easy way to start the week.  It's actually more of a word magic trick than a puzzle.  Anyone can do it!*

*Ready for a tougher challenge?  Try [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84658/d%c3%a9j%c3%a0-vu-again).*

Comment: Hey - I've gone ahead and removed the "difficulty indicator" from the title. ([relevant meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1437/can-we-please-edit-very-hard-difficult-and-easy-out-of-titles))

Comment: @Hugh — No problem.  I just wanted to advertise that this is not a highly competitive puzzle, so novices should go ahead and give it a try.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The words are:

> BROILER, **RELI**VED, **DEVI**ATED, **DETAI**LED, **DELI**VER, **REVI**VED, **DEVI**SED, **DESI**RED, **DERI**VED, **DEVI**LED, **DELI**MIT, **TIMI**NG. (Notice that the single letter I carries over the entire way through!)